# Vuejs: Get value in [__ob__: Observer]

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a return result : `console.log(this.option)`

```
[__ob__: Observer]
0:
name: "alata"
status: "4"
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get name: ƒ reactiveGetter()
```

I converted it :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.option))
console.log(obj)
```

And the result is an empty array :

```
[]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Please help me get `name` and `status` data inside it. Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `this.option.name` ?

Comment: result : `undefined`